# Can I camp in the backcountry outside backcountry campsites in Jasper National Park?

Tags: camping, national-parks, canada

In Jasper National Park, when I am hiking on trails, must I camp on designated backcountry campsites, or can I camp anywhere I want?

According to [this forum post on tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g154917-i464-k1750422-Backcountry_camping-Jasper_National_Park_Alberta.html):

> Yes, random camping along established trails is frowned upon and park regulations are enforced by wardens on patrol - on foot, on horseback, and by helicopter.

That's neither clear nor authoritative.  What are the rules that apply here?

Comment: Hmm...that's a little unclear. IIRC the standard ranger rap when you pick up a wilderness permit for the national parks in California is that you should avoid camping within 100' of trails or water. That might be the kind of thing they mean here by "camping along."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is **no, you may only camp in designated areas**. Camping is only allowed in designated areas at Jasper park. If you contact the park directly by e-mail the answer is the following:

> In Jasper National Park, when hikers are hiking on trails they must camp in the designated backcountry campsites only.

From the official Parks Canada [Backcountry Guide in Jasper National Park 2013](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/ab/jasper/activ/ap-bc.aspx) you must

> Obtain a Backcountry Camping Permit from a Park Information Centre.

and from [Parks Canada Jasper section](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/ab/jasper/activ/~/link.aspx?_id=4AB625323FF642F38BCC86E53CEEF171&_z=z)

> A **backcountry camping permit is mandatory for all overnight trips** and can be obtained by phoning the Trail Office (780) 852-6177.

These permits are obtained for specific campgrounds and/or designated sites.

In Jasper, [exceptions exist](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/ab/jasper/activ/ap-bc/bivouack.aspx) for climbers which allow them to bivouac in specific cases. You still need to obtain a backcountry camping permit.

Comment: Good Answer - another helpful link is http://www.albertaparks.ca/albertaparksca/visit-our-parks/find-a-park.aspx

Comment: @Mapperz That link documents only *provincial* parks, doesn't it?

Comment: Some are adjacent to National Parks but they have back country camping available - especially around Jasper National Park.

Comment: I can confirm that you can only camp in designated areas and that you require a wilderness pass for any backcountry overnight activity.  If you want to do stealth camping, then do it as far away from main trails/routes as possible.